# Микросервисы как разделить сервис отчетов от основного сервиса?

Tags: микросервисы

В микросервисной архитектуре надо чтобы каждый сервис имел свое хранилище, так?  Надо чтобы отдельный сервис который генерирует отчеты имел доступ к данным другого сервиса, это надо делать запросы между самими микросервисами или как? В один нельзя все перенести

Comment: Запросы между сервисами. Если это начинает нарягать БД, надо производить оптимизации.

Comment: @Etki, так мне надо достаточно много информации забрать чтобы сгенерировать отчет, а запросов между сервисами много быть не должно!

Comment: приведите конкретный кейс. запросов может быть много, они все должны быть условными-бесплатными.

Comment: Мне нужно много данных например вопросы ответы пользователи их страны и результаты опросов , как это условно-бесплатными? Можно сделать запросы между процессами бесплатными? Как это

Comment: При столь неподробном объяснении не совсем уверен, но попробую предположить, что где-то непонимание и выделять здесь что-то в отдельный сервис вообще не нужно

Comment: Я не буду расписывать свою модель, если не выносить в отдельный сервис, то я впихну сервис отчетов который генерирует документы туда куда мне не надо, его некуда впихнуть. Я написал детально, мне надо статистику по опросам сделать, собрать информацию как-то надо

Comment: у вас нет особых вариантов кроме получения всех этих данных запросами.

Comment: имхо, сервису отчетов никакое хранилище не нужно. он должен запросить данные у другого сервиса (или сразу из бд) трансформировать (агрегировать например) если нужно и послать их дальше, тому, кто их запросил, другому сервису (например фронтэнду), чистый стейтлесс трансформ.

Comment: @YuraIvanov, ну не может он обращаться сразу к бд, а получать данные тогда нужно с многих сервисов. CQRS Event Sourcing решает эту проблему?

Comment: опять таки, имхо, микросервисы не должны знать у кого (из скольких источников) они запрашивают данные, работа каждого микросервиса сводит к одному действию, избегая сколько-нибудь сильного связывания. Грубо говоря, frontend->rmq->отчеты->rmq->(mongo, redis непосредственно или read service)->rmq->отчеты->rmq->frontend. Если данные собираются из нескольких мест, значит это ответственность отдельного сервиса. CQRS Event Sourcing к "отчетам" имеет отдаленное отношение, т.к. этот слой общения (read и тем более write) должен быть на плечах другого сервиса.

Comment: @YuraIvanov, что значит read service? и как  rmq напрямую -> к монго обращается, можете детально объяснить эту стрелочку в вашем ответе, спасибо

Comment: та стрелочка для сервиса. если есть прямой доступ к монго, значит напрямую без рэббита. это было "грубо говоря"... просто если можно обойтись агрегацией в монго, то промежуточный сервис не нужен. все зависит от структуры сервисов и данных... важный момент в микросервисах: в каждом сервисе не делать лишнего, делать проще и очень желательно что-то одно.

Comment: @YuraIvanov, как можно агрегацию делать в монго если там много разных инстансов и они независимы в принципе Какой промежуточный сервис между моими отчетами этими? Зачем его создавать еще один

Comment: @vkovalchuk88 вы задаете вопросы, не раскрывая подробностей своей структуры. в своих комментариях я попытался максимально абстрактно предложить решение. Могу сказать в дополнение только одно, если у вас возникает вопрос "зачем еще один сервис?" возникает ощущение, что вы двигаетесь в сторону монолита, тогда микросервисы вам не м.б. не нужны? имхо.

Comment: @YuraIvanov, ну у меня один вопрос, сейчас уже стоит, как мне сделать эту агрегацию, если для кажддого сервиса своя БД. В каком месте? В отдельном сервисе? У меня проект на микросервисах, я пока не очень понимаю, вот и спрашиваю